# Why was this Shrek question closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This question: [Was Fiona actually cursed to be a human?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189549/58193) in the [shrek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shrek) tag is currently closed. I can't for the life of me work out why it is closed at the moment, never mind closed as off topic with the reason.

> This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the help center.

Now normally I would just vote to reopen this myself but I have already done so and it has also had quite a history itself so best to discuss first rather than carry on the close/reopen war. Looking at the [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/189549/timeline) it has:

- Been closed
- Been reopened
- Been closed again
- Left closed in the reopen queue

So before anyone takes any action on this post can we reach a consensus here, i.e. don't VTRO it yet if you think it should be reopened.

So should this question be open or closed?

Comment: I honestly have no idea.  There was a comment detailing someone's close reason (speculation? and false premise), that comment was removed.  I had left a comment stating that wasn't a valid reason, and to answer the facts in error instead, that comment was also removed.  I gave up.  I get the impression the community wants it closed because they think it's a stupid question.  Like that never happens around here.

Comment: @Radhil That is most likely the reason i.e. super downvotes. FWIW the comments you mention, I flagged them as "No Longer Needed" when the question was initially reopened. I didn't see it go back into the Close queue because I was off the site at that point.

Comment: I'm guessing that it was closed because it's based on a false premise - that's happened before. Being based on a false premise can sometimes make it *unclear what the you're asking*, but generally it should just be left open and the false premise corrected.

Comment: I've reopened it. It's not a terrible question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can understand why the question may have been closed as POB in the first round. It wasn't a "great" question and did seem to invite specuation. However, that was fixable by a simple edit (which you did).

It still was not a great question, but there was no reason for the question to be closed as *"not about science fiction or fantasy"*. Shrek is clearly an on-topic work.

Even if there was misunderstanding of the OP of what happened in the series, that happens ALL. THE TIME. There are numerous questions where the OP is wrong and is corrected by canon source.

**Summarily, this question should be reopened and remain open.**

Comment: Looks like it's been reopened now.